# ggplot counting observations in each quadrant

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data as below:

```
# A tibble: 158 x 2
       X      Y
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.71 -2.39 
 2  0.92  0.573
 3 -2.52 -1.61 
 4  3.88  5.43 
 5  0.15  0.106
 6  3.49  6.66 
 7 -0.54  0.613
 8  1.4   4.21 
 9  1.16  0.107
10 -3.37 -3.62 
# ... with 148 more rows
```

I plot the observations and draw a line horizontally and vertically at 0 using:

```
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = X,
               y = Y)) +
    geom_point() +
    #geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0))
```

What I would like to do now is count the number of points which are in each quadrant of the plot and just display the number on each of the quadrant.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(-0.71, 0.92, -2.52, 3.88, 0.15, 3.49, -0.54, 
1.4, 1.16, -3.37, -0.55, -0.74, 2.13, 1.33, 3.27, 1.74, 0.65, 
1.23, -1.75, 0.9, 3.86, 3.69, -1.74, -3.43, 0.67, 3.83, 2.32, 
-5.46, -0.55, -6.39, -2.23, -1.3, 4.72, 2.42, -7.9, -1.54, 0.99, 
-9.97, -18.41, -7.73, 1.5, -7.5, -9.88, 8.82, 10.48, 6.7, -0.23, 
8.15, 3.02, 4.54, -2.76, 5.77, 3.03, -3.63, 3.71, 6.27, 1.92, 
-7.86, -5.5, -4.44, 9.47, 3.89, 0.81, 6.83, 1.98, 4.01, 0.43, 
2.79, -1.48, -1.87, -5.93, -8.58, 11.56, -0.46, 0.33, 5.27, 4.32, 
2.4, -0.64, -6.7, 3.74, 1.01, 2.76, 2.8, -1.63, 0.65, 1.3, 5.33, 
0.96, 3.71, 1.27, 2.53, -1.52, 5.69, -2.53, 3.82, 4.09, 2.79, 
2.64, -3.42, 4.72, 0.62, 0.25, 1.98, 2.82, -2.06, 4.06, -2.45, 
2.03, 2.22, -0.2, -3.47, 6.15, -1.2, 1.11, 1, -1.71, 1.05, -5.93, 
-3.35, 7.53, 0.45, -2.45, -5.73, 0.26, 7, 1.12, 1.39, -0.11, 
0.43, 0.34, -2.05, 4.54, 1.76, 2.15, 3.26, 0.2, 0.84, 0.93, 0.98, 
1.97, 0.07, 2.48, 1.98, 2.88, 1.18, 5.23, -3.95, -2.17, 0.35, 
2.51, 0.39, 3.11, 3.09, 0.06, -7.81, 1.62, -9.53), Y = c(-2.38916419707325, 
0.572675136581781, -1.61130358515631, 5.42706994951004, 0.105533424368025, 
6.65697289481407, 0.613486039256266, 4.21013704773222, 0.106990463992386, 
-3.62352710962904, -0.203607589793183, -4.24563967581072, 2.97070300267885, 
2.92544516479698, 5.02538739147422, 2.25461465260415, 1.66492554339803, 
3.5690423154001, 0.108411247307002, 0.961008630173696, 3.79172784045593, 
1.94108347244724, -2.12992072359958, -5.87473482253699, -1.45100684091412, 
1.47842234462587, 1.43196010231586, -7.74290369146724, -2.79056547363334, 
-5.03532133668577, -1.99400739381075, -2.92320856826413, 3.93394610595585, 
3.29451174347621, -10.0410470556235, 3.34517672842812, 2.41625183369762, 
-10.3476519710384, -21.791966984666, -11.1142687331988, 3.32761656369176, 
-3.96223311815655, -11.093184503697, 11.6694167237026, 22.2461574652919, 
9.28255170483023, 4.63817899423635, 11.8553670456421, 8.27889381692159, 
8.19911670446593, -6.470817611772, 3.09218109975165, 7.5825172514382, 
0.0284717847140023, 4.90864483240255, 10.0311544305095, 8.55401150272708, 
-8.84107625063785, -8.04105369987643, -6.65872061590883, 10.8577722872979, 
4.03706922467202, 3.04148092466194, 8.90634921641063, 1.56555573277521, 
4.42535372370123, 0.841035482771217, 1.75578768128183, -2.67241757153407, 
-2.25418139889371, -8.7723458397205, -11.2420616969584, 11.4836809985778, 
-1.8649021388476, 0.832085873992507, 11.6062841497052, 2.59039949751966, 
2.28509371230735, -1.97715071813135, -7.3280081242774, 3.97121830333205, 
-0.569284938256821, 2.31082313266322, 3.02490478503254, -1.38512132143018, 
-0.866847983058995, 2.97552563660034, 5.95976111047322, -0.102502393594657, 
4.58003409048615, 0.842834319309465, 3.06786040532266, 0.250639945095402, 
6.78696057469418, -1.62606880448011, 5.46367912370997, 2.53357559730344, 
4.73895950607308, 2.50934817572881, -0.312149263565189, 4.82621271905962, 
-0.79009628184665, -3.12115495501355, -0.461711220579862, 4.27359516836912, 
-4.60871127364226, 3.84488020178729, -5.26245849925393, 3.54222359765326, 
1.04191534953213, 1.4982293818719, -3.56618092951384, 4.95478586278666, 
-0.270584959088251, -0.900452947549406, 0.901254072925249, -0.254483190258712, 
-2.63217404877559, -4.71624328721887, -7.1747474980974, 4.86036342835152, 
3.24549729559669, -4.19219918146311, -10.128570960197, 0.803895306904637, 
9.33865112323734, 2.85517888612945, 0.316844258915139, -0.151669189522978, 
1.00839469793829, 1.57398998124214, -5.0607247073979, 8.91704977465508, 
2.59984205825244, 1.31737969318745, 2.70804837397023, 1.80193676584248, 
1.48362026996833, -2.11380109244311, 3.54300752215851, 1.6501194298151, 
-1.01504840432201, 6.74326962933175, 0.1866931051541, 2.9825290286452, 
1.42593783576641, 2.71110274944611, -4.09572797775837, 1.50144422897237, 
-0.552818435076999, 5.23843746771127, 1.33321908169899, 1.28745947800351, 
2.60490918566195, -1.54038908822145, -9.6363012621261, -0.190177144865133, 
-13.0653210889016)), row.names = c(NA, -158L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do a `stat_summary` for this. I haven't been able to figure it out, but I'm tossing the idea out there in hopes that someone else can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
quad_count <- df %>%
  # Count how many with each combination of X and Y being positive
  count(right = X > 0, top = Y > 0) %>%
  # TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0, so these map the TRUE to +1 and FALSE to -1
  mutate(X = 2 * (right - 0.5), Y = 2 * (top - 0.5))

  df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0)) +
  # This layer should use the other dataset, but keep using X and Y for location
  geom_text(data = quad_count, aes(label = n), size = 10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = X,
               y = Y)) +
    geom_point() +
    #geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0)) +
    geom_text(data = df %>%
                  mutate(X = X >= 0, Y = Y >= 0) %>%
                  count(X, Y) %>%
                  mutate(X = if_else(X, 10, -10),
                         Y = if_else(Y, 10, -10)),
              mapping = aes(X, Y, label = n), size = 10)
```

Comment: please provide an explanation of your solution to go along with the code.